# Stop Client from seing all internal Case Status values changes on the Client Portal

Tags: community, case, process, support, status

Our clients have the possibility to create a Case from the client Portal. All cases creating by a client have the default status

- **New**

When dealing with the case, the case status may change to other values:

- Information Needed
- **In Progress**
- Escalated
- QA Pending
- Resolved
- **Closed**

But I do not want the client to see all the internal status changes
Ideally, I would like the client to see only **3 status values**:

- **New**
- **In Progress**
- **Closed**

Which means that when the case status changes internally to:

- Information Needed
- Escalated
- QA Pending
- Resolved

The client (on the portal) should only see "**In Progress**".
How can I achieved that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to find the answer to my question.

First, I edited to CSS on community with
/* CASE DETAIL- Hides all page layout sections >= 2 */
.comm-page-detail-500 .test-id__section.slds-section:nth-child(N+2) {display:none !important;}

Then I created a customer status field (formula type) that I added to the client layout
e.g.

```
CASE(
     Status,

     'Open', 'In Progress',

     'Escalated', 'In Progress',

     'Resolved', 'In Progress',

     'Closed', 'Closed',

     'New' )
```

With this the client only sees the status New, In Progress, Closed